# auditing of symlink/symlinkat syscalls doesn't work here

Tags: symlink, linux-audit

I'm trying to monitor symlink/symlinkat syscalls of files under a specific directory, so I added two rules:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S symlinkat -F success=1 -F dir=/XX
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S symlink -F success=1 -F dir=/XX
```

But when I do `ln -s /XX/aa /tmp/bb` there're no logs.

(I can confirm auditd is running correctly, because other rules I've added works fine.)

So, is it impossible to monitor symlinks in this situation?

**EDIT**

Seems like a kernel bug, if the source of file to link resides in /XX, it doesn't work; But if the target location is within /XX, it works

e.g

```
ln -s /XX/file /tmp/xx   # doesn't trigger alert
cd /XX; ln -s /bin/ls xx # triggers alert
```

Comment: Does it work in other directories? Could this be a filesystem issue? What filesystem is the directory on?

Comment: @terdon It's a ext2 fs

Comment: @terdon seems like to be a kernel bug, see my update